# Leave Management System

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am working on a project Leave Management System,By using MySql DB,In that i am adding dates in holiday table after saveing dates i have to display those dates into calender how?

```
1   New Year    2016-12-31  2017-01-01
2   Pongal      2016-01-13  2017-01-17
4   Repablicday 2017-01-26  2017-01-27
5   Lovers Day  2017-02-14  2017-02-15
12  Holi        2017-03-02  2017-03-01
13  IndependenceDay 2017-08-16  2017-08-15
14  Holiday     2017-01-03  2017-01-02
15  hasgf       2017-01-08  2017-01-07
16  hasgf       2017-01-18  2017-01-17
```

Comment: Calender? which calender? are you using any **plugin?**

Comment: No ia m using asp calender control

Comment: Any other alternative you are allowed??

Comment: From the MS help on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/add3s294.aspx, we find _you create a method for the control's DayRender event, which is raised as each day in the current calendar month is being rendered_ Which leads to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228044.aspx. Honestly does anyone even google anymore?

Comment: @Ramu please check various references! Add your code to post and not in the comment. if you still face some error update the same to post. we shall help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a third party calendar control. Not all calendars will work for you so you have to find a good one. There are many free calendar controls in the market at this moment. I have used essential object calendar when I developed [Leave Monitor](http://www.LeaveMonitor.com) system that looks like this:

[image]

You can try that.